# Python to C# code conversion

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to convert the python line of code below to C#:

```
encoded_c = chr(abs(ord(string[i]) - ord(key_c) % 256))
```

This is what I got in C#:

```
char encoded_c=(char)Math.Abs((int)decodedString[i] - (int)key_c % 256);
```

However, it doesn't return the same result. I think it has to do with the (int) castings, but when I tried searching for other methods of ord() or (int) they didn't seem to work.

For reference , here's the whole block of code:

Python:

```
def basic_decode(key,string):

    decoded_chars=[]

    string=base64.urlsafe_b64decode(string)

    string=base64.b64decode(string)

    for i in xrange(len(string)):

        key_c=key[i % len(key)]

        encoded_c = chr(abs(ord(string[i]) - ord(key_c) % 256))

        decoded_chars.append(encoded_c)

    decoded_string="".join(decoded_chars)

    return decoded_string
```

C#:

```
public string basic_decode(string key,string message)
    {
        List<int> decoded_chars = new List<int>();

        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(message);

        string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

        data = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedString);

        decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, decodedString.Length))
        {
            char key_c = key[i % key.Length];

            char encoded_c=(char)Math.Abs((int)decodedString[i] - (int)key_c % 256); //this line doesnt return what it's supposed to

            decoded_chars.Add(encoded_c);
        } 
        string decoded_string = string.Join("",decoded_chars);
        return decoded_string;
    }
```

When executing the C# function with:

```
Console.WriteLine(t.basic_decode("test", "NGNybTU5WE0yQT09"));
```

Note: NGNybTU5WE0yQT09 : Is an encoded string that was encoded with encode function(With the python version, it encodes and decodes perfectly).

It returns

?

?

?

?

?

?

?

6541765432654186541765417643265418

The question marks refer to:

```
Console.WriteLine(encoded_c);
```

Which is located under the char encoded_c=.... line of code

When

```
print basic_decode("test","NGNybTU5WE0yQT09")
```

Is executed, it returns:

m

e

s

s

a

g

e

message

message is the correct decoded message

Comment: What is `basic_decode` supposed to do?

Comment: `"I think it has to do with the (int) castings"` - Well, does it?  When you debug this, which operation is producing a different result for the same input?  There are several operations happening on that one line of code.  Break them apart into multiple lines of code.  Step through them in a debugger.  For any given input, which one produces a different output than in Python?  What was that input and what were the two outputs?

Comment: @HristoYankov It's meant to decode a message. I can paste the encoding function if it helps..

Comment: @David I checked the output of both versions , but when I went to use "Console.WriteLine(encoded_c)" the output was literally "????" and in python it was random characters.

Comment: @Tom: I count 6 different operations on that one line of code.  *Which one* first produces an unexpected result?  What is the input and what are the differing outputs?

Comment: @David I'm not sure if this could be the problem or just C# but the second base64 conversion returns "???????" but python returns "áÊæçÕÌØ". The first base64 conversion for both return the same value.

Comment: @David The problem is (int)decodedString[i] . For the first for statement run through , C# returns 65533 and python returns 225. Would it have to do with the obscure characters?

Comment: The problem might be before that. When I step through the method, the value of `decodedString` before the foreach loop is `"�������"`. Try comparing that to your Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there are two problems that I found with your converted code. First, the second `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` is throwing off the input. For example, the integer equivalent of the first character in the Python code is 225, but in the C# code it is 65533. You can get around this by skipping the second encoding altogether and just using `data`.

The second is that you are using a `List<int>` to store the result characters. When you then use `string.Join` to create the result string, you are combining a bunch of integers into a string, which is why the output is a bunch of numbers. Change the list to be a `List<char>` and it will produce the correct result.

Functional code:

```
public string basic_decode(string key, string message)
{
    List<char> decoded_chars = new List<char>();

    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(message);

    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    data = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedString);

    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length))
    {
        char key_c = key[i % key.Length];

        char encoded_c = (char)Math.Abs((int)data[i] - (int)key_c % 256); 

        decoded_chars.Add(encoded_c);
    }

    string decoded_string = string.Join("", decoded_chars);
    return decoded_string;
}
```

Tested with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dec = basic_decode("test", "NGNybTU5WE0yQT09");
    Console.WriteLine(dec);
}

// Prints:
// 
// message
```

Comment: People should start realizing the difference between datatypes.. Using int instead of char can lead to a whole unexpected behavior in places that are so far away from the real cause of problem which is frustrating. Good answer there..

Comment: @AmmarSalman It's not a wholly unexpected error to make, considering the source script is python. If OP is used to developing in weakly- or dynamically-typed languages like Python, the difference between `int` and `char` might not be obvious.

Comment: @Abion47 Thanks for the great answer man. I think I may have to look up more about datatypes to avoid such a problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is an automated online conversion tool you can try here:

https://pythoncsharp.com/

I think you know what to expect with an automated conversion. It will probably not compile but will be valid syntax, which is a good enough basis for a manual conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_list(list_to_sort):
    """
    Sorts the given list in ascending order and returns it.
    """
    return sorted(list_to_sort)

def reverse_list(list_to_reverse):
    """
    Reverses the given list and returns it.
    """
    return list_to_reverse[::-1]

my_list = [10, 7, 5, 2, 1]
print("Original list:", my_list)

sorted_list = sort_list(my_list)
print("Sorted list:", sorted_list)

reversed_list = reverse_list(sorted_list)
print("Reversed list:", reversed_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**